# Getting rid of white spots on front teeth

Tags: dentistry, home-remedies, stain-removal-teeth, white-strips-teeth

Wearing braces can lead to some very visible color changes.

Very often some parts are darker than others and "white spots" appear.

Heavy brushing of the teeth is not a good idea since this will not work well and also erodes too much of the enamel.

If a professional teeth whitening performed by a dentist is not preferred or not an option then other remedies that are often recommended include special toothpastes, sodium bicarbonate or over the counter whitening strips.

These options may be [unsafe](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/721/43) or ineffective.

What options do exist to improve the aesthetics of the teeth in such a situation?
Mainly this means: how were these spots formed and how to get rid of the white spots safely?

Comment: The personalised parts of this question are a problem on this site. Please edit your question to make it more general. Teeth aesthetics while minding (tooth) health is interesting.

Comment: @LangLangC How Can I generalize it ?

Comment: Tried a heavy rephrasing. I hope I captured all of your intents. If you are not satisfied please [edit](https://health.stackexchange.com/posts/14095/edit) it to your liking.

Comment: @LangLangC Thanks for the great edit :) I will retract my close vote as soon as I get my hands on a computer

Comment: @LangLangC Looks great,thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently, there are three options to deal with white spots in frontal teeth after orthodontic treatment:

1. remineralization,
2. micro-abrasion, and
3. resin infiltration.

There are several case report about micro-abrasion and resin infiltration, and some clinical trials about all, but a recent [systematic review](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/27030284) found the evidence of effectiveness was rated as low, that means that the results are inconsistent or there is a high risk of bias, i.e. the manufacturers of the products published the results.

The three options are different: 
**Remineralization** uses fluoride aiming to add something to the surfaces layer of the tooth.   There are some clinical trials showing positive results (ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19887683) and others showing no effect (ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/27480987). But the advantge of a non invasive therapy is that there is no loss of enamel surface, hence there is no irreversible alteration to the tooth surface.

**Microabrasion** on the other hand smooth irreversibly the surface of the eroded enamel with an acid.

Finally, **infiltration**, also irreversibly treatment, use an acid to remove a small layer of the eroded enamel and then add a resin layer. From the esthetic point of view this solve the issue immediately, but the lack of prospective studies add an interrogation mark to the long term results.

Hence, from all the three options, currently the [remineralization](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/27907894) is the only that is non-invasive.

Comment: for the remineralization I found GC Tooth Mouss .Can this help me with the spots?

Comment: Is not clear whether might be useful or not. There are some clinical trials showing positive results (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19887683) and others showing no effect (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/27480987). But the advantge of a non invasive therapy is that there is no loss of enamel surface, hence, is safe to try.

Comment: @sergiouribe Important additions to your answer are best presented by editing them into your answer. Comments are volatile and subject to permanent deletion.

Comment: What about  hydrogen peroxide ? Is it safe ?

Comment: @Ciolte Alin Did the answer provided answer the question?  If the answer was useful, mark as solved, if not then clarify which point of the question remains unanswered. If you are asking for a personal condition, I would reccomend to visit any ADA certified dentist with your specific condition.

Comment: @LangLangC agreed, added to the answer